# trimspool on has no effect to remove trailing blanks

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I'm loading a text file from a db table having 300 million rows.

In each row I have two columns.

What I have tried so far is:

```
set feedback off
set heading off
set echo off
set termout off
set trimout on
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 30000
set verify off
set long 100000 

spool ...\\trial.txt;
select column1 || ','|| column2 from TABLE;
spool off
```

But every time I end up trailing blanks. e.g. (dots representing blanks)

```
117258,30759.......................................................
279576,38463.......................................................
99200,11223........................................................
```

What might I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try applying trim function to both columns.
select trim(column1) || ','|| trim(column2) from TABLE;

Also - if you're trying to export data from oracle to a csv, its better to use one of oracle's build in packages, such as UTL_FILE.